# VBA Variable Definition - Which Data Type Should I use?

Tags: vba, variables, definition

I am new to programming and would like to know when writing code how I should define my variables.  I understand that I should use strings for words etc., but when using numbers with decimal points for calculations such as multiply or divide, should I use Single, Double etc.??

Answer (score 0):

VB can use and VBS can only use Variants. These datatypes don't require declaration as they autoconvert. EG `x = "27.5"` will work if `y = x / 55`. You don't need to think about datatypes.

Variants are slower. For small programs this is irrelevent. Although be careful in loops. They can always be coerced.

Using Variants leads to a clean programming style where program logic rather than binary implementation is front and centre.

In VB you mostly use COM which uses Variants.

Answer (score -1):

If you're new to programming, suggest keeping it simple and use `Double`. `Double` is the native type for most math functions. It can tend to be faster, but these days, all the numeric types seem to have the same performance.

`Single` is useful for conserving space when you don't need extra precision. `Single` would be okay, too, but better to stick with one type and use it consistently.